# What is the time complexity of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
int func3(int n){
  if (n <= 1) return n;
  return func3(n - 1) + func3(n - 1);}
```

My thinking is: in every recursion we have an addition operation. And we do this operation every time we divide the recursion into two. So I am not sure if I should call it `O(N2^N)` or `O(2^N)`. I think that `O(N2^N)` makes more sense since we are dividing the problem into 2^N pieces and adding them separately. Still though I am unsure. So can someone guide me through by showing their steps?

Comment: As it stands, it's exponential, but you can easily change it to linear by calculating the value of `func3(n-1)` just once, i.e. `tmp = func3(n-1); return tmp+tmp`, or just `return 2*func3(n-1)`

Comment: We don't know the time complexity of func3, since you don't define it.  That being said, why do you not just return `2 * func3(n-1)`?

Comment: n = 1: 1 call, n = 2: 2 calls, n = 3: 4 calls, n = 4: 8 calls etc - O(2^N)

Comment: @AlexSalauyou I see, but should we also not consider the addition progress?

Comment: @Huzo everything progressing slower is included in big-O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the calls to your functions as a binary tree:

```
    func3
     /\
 func3 func3
.............
```

You will have `n` levels of nodes in your binary tree, each `next_level_node_count =  perv_level_node_count * 2`.

That's a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to form a recurrence equation for the function and solve it. The given function can be represented as

```
T(1) = O(1)
T(n) = 2 * T(n-1)
```

When you expand the recurrence as below, we get **T(n) = 2^n**

```
T(n) = 2 * { 2 * T(n-2) } = 2^2 * T(n-2)
   = 2^3 * T(n-3)
   = 2^(n-1) * T(n-(n-1))
   = 2^(n-1) * O(1)
   = 2^(n-1)
   = 2^n
```

Hope it helps!